# How can I get Create A World to find my game data?

Tags: steam, the-sims-3

I downloaded the most recent version of CAW from The Sims 3 website and I have a copy of The Sims 3 on Steam that is completely up-to-date. When I try to run the editor, I get a message saying "Game data not found." and then it closes.

I searched around and found posts about this problem going back several years, but no solutions. Does one exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a user on the Steam forums that has laid out a [solution to this problem.](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=23435546&postcount=4)  It has worked for other users in the [topic](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=23435546).  It involves a bit of meddling with the registry, be careful to only change keys listed in this post.  The original post is a bit clustered; the steps are laid out below:

1. Open your start menu, type **regedit** and press Enter.

   a. (For 64-bit versions of Windows) Navigate to key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE\Sims(Steam) by using the drop arrows next to the folders.

   b. (for 32-bit versions of Windows) Navigate to key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sims(Steam) by using the drop arrows next to the folders.
2. Right click on the folder for Sims(Steam) and select **Export**.
3. Save the file to your Desktop as whatever you choose, **make sure that it is saving as type: Win9x\NT4 Registration Files**, it can be selected in the drop down under the box for inputting the name of the file.
4. Right Click the file saved to your Desktop and select **Edit**.
5. **Replace** all instances of **Sims(Steam)** with **Sims**, then **save** your changes.
6. Go back to the Registry Editor, then open the **File** menu and select **Import**.
7. Find the file that you just edited and click **Open**.
8. Reboot, your Create-A-World should now work.

Answer (score -2):

**Here is what I found that fixed it for some people:**

---

The Sims 3 Create A World Game Data [Not Found Error](http://www.modthesims.info/showthread.php?t=430308)

Sims 3 [Create-A-World problem. [SOLVED]](http://games4theworld.bestgoo.com/t6373-sims-3-create-a-world-problem-solved)

Basically:

1. Make sure your game is up to date.
2. Uninstall your current version of CAW(Google: How to uninstall a program if you don't know)
3. Download the [LATEST version of CAW](http://llnw.thesims3.com/content/global/downloads/caw/worldtool.exe)
4. Install LATEST version you just downloaded.
5. Run it, it should work now.

---

**Good luck, hope I helped!**

Comment: This is not a helpful answer since I already stated in my question that both my game and CAW is up to date. I appreciate you trying to help, but this answer is not what I'm looking for :(

Comment: Did you read the threads I linked to check if you could find something else in them that could help?

Comment: Yeah, I did, unfortunately :/